# How do you do https POST request using Volley (Android)?

Tags: java, android, https, android-volley

Android app gives an error on POST request:

> com.android.volley.NoConnectionError:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.

After google search I have discovered this error might be related to Unknown certificate authority.

**So my questions are:**

What certification authority service do you use to prevent this error?

This is my POST code below, perhaps there are some mistakes? - I use httpS in my url.

```
private void userRegistration(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url + REG, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Все прошло хорошо!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected java.util.Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            java.util.Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(EMAIL, userEmail);
            params.put(PASSWORD, userPass);
            return params;
        }
    };
    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

**I have already read these:**

- [Official android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa) about this mistake.
- Some related questions ([Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673568/does-android-volley-support-ssl/32674422) and [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555404/https-request-using-volley)) on stackoverflow. Q1
  (BNK answer) actually works for me and solved the problem but I
  believe there is a better way to work with HTTPS in Android.
- [This one](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/using-android-volley-with-self-signed-certificate/) didn't work for me.

Help me please! What the common way (best practices) to work with https using Volley? Maybe it just to buy certificate from well know authorities?

Comment: Is this for all versions of Android or only some (like 2.x)?

Comment: @Tigger - minSdkVersion 21 targetSdkVersion 26. Tested on 5, 6, 7 Android versions.